# How to in Laravel 8 store exception in database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to store catched exception to Logs table in database.

I used this code in Laravel 6 and all works fine, but in Laravel 8 don't work and I can't figure

**App\Exceptions\LogsException.php**

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        Logs::create([
            'user_id' => auth()->id(),
            'method' => $request->method(),
            'url' => $request->fullUrl(),
            'file' => $exception->getFile(),
            'line' => $exception->getLine(),
            'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
        ]); 
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

**All Controllers**

```
catch(Throwable $exc) {
    throw new LogsException($exc);
}
```

**Handler.php** - This part not working in Laravel 8

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{    
    if ($exception instanceof \App\Exceptions\LogsException) {
        return $exception->render($request, $exception);
    }
        
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

In Laravel 8 Handle.php logic changed and I don't know how to same option implement in Laravel 8

Thanks in advance

Comment: whats the error you got?

Comment: @EsTeAa 
Too few arguments to function App\Exceptions\LogsException::render(), 1 passed in ...\Exceptions\Handler.php on line 324 and exactly 2 expected...

As i said this code works on Laravel 6, but in the new version Laravel 8 error and I can't figure how to change Handle.php file to work the same as in Laravel 6

Comment: You can try with delete the param `$request`